# GSON - Convert Object that has a Generic List in to JSON String

Tags: java, json, spring, gson

I am seeing an empty response "{}" when I run the below. Employee class has a list which I assume is causing the issue. please can you let me know how I can overcome this?

```
public class ServiceValidationTest {

private Gson gson;

public ServiceValidationTest() {
    this.setGson(new GsonBuilder()
            .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
            .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(byte[].class,
                    new GsonByteArrayHandler())
            .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(boolean.class,
                    new GsonBooleanHandler())
            .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Date.class,
                    new GsonDateHandler())
            .create());
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    List<Grade> grades = new ArrayList<Grade>();
    grades.add(new Grade("1"));
    grades.add(new Grade("2"));
    grades.add(new Grade("3"));
    grades.add(new Grade("4"));

    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setGrades(grades);
    employee.setName("someone");

    System.out.println(new ServiceValidationTest().getGson().toJson(employee));

}

public Gson getGson() {
    return gson;
}

public void setGson(Gson gson) {
    this.gson = gson;
}
```

}

**Employee Class**

```
package com.test;

import java.util.List;

public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private List<Grade> grades;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<Grade> getGrades() {
        return grades;
    }
    public void setGrades(List<Grade> grades) {
        this.grades = grades;
    }
}
```

**Grade**

```
package com.test;

public class Grade {



    public Grade(String grade) {
        super();
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    private String grade;

    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(String grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }



}
```

**EDIT**

I figured out that the below code is causing the issue. If if declare new gson() and use the gson object , it is working as expected -

```
        this.setGson(new GsonBuilder()
            .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
            .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(byte[].class,
                    new GsonByteArrayHandler())
            .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(boolean.class,
                    new GsonBooleanHandler())
            .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Date.class,
                    new GsonDateHandler())
            .create());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused to excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation() which was excluding the all fields that weren't annotated to be not serialized. When I added the annotation similar to what is listed below , the fields were serialized.

**EMPLOYEE**

```
package com.test;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Employee {

    @Expose @SerializedName("NAME") 
    private String name;
    @Expose @SerializedName("GRADES") 
    private List<Grade> grades;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<Grade> getGrades() {
        return grades;
    }
    public void setGrades(List<Grade> grades) {
        this.grades = grades;
    }
}
```

**GRADE**

```
package com.test;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Grade {



    public Grade(String grade) {
        super();
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    @Expose @SerializedName("GRADE") 
    private String grade;

    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(String grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }



}
```